# ShopifySharp Update FulFillment Obsolete

Tags: c#, shopify, shopify-api, shopifysharp

I have been using ShopifySharp for quite a while and have recently updated to the latest version.

I have noticed that

```
public virtual async Task<Fulfillment> UpdateAsync(long orderId, long fulfillmentId, Fulfillment fulfillment, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
```

has been marked as **obsolete**.

I am struggling to work out what the replacement is, or if there is a replacement.

My scenario is that a human creates a fulfillment. A webhook fires and sends me the the json, i produce a shipping label, and then i go back and update the fulfillment with the tracking number and courier name.

Does anyone know how the process of updating a fulfillment has changed please?

How would i fulfill my scenario without an "Update Fufillment" function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

so it looks like the UpdateTrackingAsync does the job.